# how to search in enum type in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

i have following code:

```
typedef enum Types{
Type_1, Type_2, Type_3
} MyTypes;

typedef union Tree{
struct {
int MyType;
}structAccessor;
} MyTree;
```

and i'm creating trees like this:

```
MyTree* node(MyTypes MyType).......//folowwing is unnecessary
```

and i would like to know how i can find the type of my tree, something like this:

```
if(node->structAccessor.MyType == MyTypes[2]) //if MyType is Type_2, i want to compare this, thanks so much
```

Answer (score 0):

`enum`s in C are always of type `int`.

You can test it against any `int` like

```
if (node->structAccessor.MyType == Type_1)
```

Though they are commonly used in `switch` statements

```
switch (node->structAccessor.MyType) {
    case Type_1:
    ...
    case Type_2:
    ...
    case Type_3:
    ...
    default: // error
}
```